# GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY binding blank screen

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY to send multiple textures to fragment shaders.

```
int width, height;

unsigned char* image1 = SOIL_load_image("border_small.png",&width, &height,0,SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
unsigned char* image2 = SOIL_load_image("tile1_small.png", &width, &height,0,SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);


glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
GLuint textures;
glGenTextures(1, &textures);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textures);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(p_myGLSL->getProgramID(),"baseTextures"), 1);

glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA, width, height, 2);

glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,
                0,0,
                1,
                width, height,
                1,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                image1);

glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                0,
                0,0,
                2,
                width, height,
                1,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                image2);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Fragment shader:

```
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2DArray baseTextures;
FragColor = texture(baseTextures, vec3(TexCoord.xy, 0));
```

The code generate a blank screen. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are copying the data in `offset = 1 and 2` of the texture unit but reading the `offset = 0` in the fragment shader.

Comment: Thanks. I set back offset to 0 and 1, and shader offset to be either 0 or 1 and still get blank screen. I double checked that image1 and image2 have data.

Comment: @DzungNguyen `glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA, width, height, 2);` should change to `glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 2);`. Because this is the internal format, so it should also say how big is each element of the texture.

Comment: YES, it worked! Could you please elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @DzungNguyen GL_RGBA is a format not internal format. If you have a look on `glTexImage2D` function, you have both `format` and `internal format` in arguments. a format will only says how many components does it have and is mostly about how it is stored in the memory on CPU side but internal format is going to describe which components does it have and how big is each element and is mostly about how it is going to be stored on GPU side.

So, you were using `format` instead of `internal format` in the `glTexStorage3D` function.